# Understanding Decorators

Tags: python

I am trying to understand Decorators and am slightly confused by the code below:

```
def smart_divide(func):
    def inner(a,b):
        print("I am going to divide",a,"and",b)
        if b == 0:
            print("Whoops! cannot divide")
            return

        return func(a,b) #In understand everything upto this point. How come when the function
                         #is called here there is no Error as we are still diving 2 by 0?
    return inner

@smart_divide
def divide(a,b):
    return a/b

print divide(2,0)
```

Thanks

Comment: what is your issue, what is not working for you here

Comment: When you try to divide by 0 you execute the print statement and then immediately return from the function, so you never execute the second return statement.

Comment: if you ask me, that's an awful example of decorator usage. Something like `@assertparamnotzero(1)` would be reusable, this is not and you'd be better off checking `b==0` in `divide()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How come when the function is called here there is no Error as we are still diving 2 by 0?

If `b` is zero, the decorated function returns earlier:

```
if b == 0:
    print("Whoops! cannot divide")
    return
```

and the division by zero is never performed. Instead, the function implicitly returns `None` (which, if you ask me, is a somewhat odd choice).